# Get ID after inserting in database using Entity Framework and Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, insert, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Windows Forms project and a database. I want to insert a record (create a new clinic) in a table `clinic`.

My method in my windows form is :

```
private async void insertToDB(string uri , object DTO ) 
{
    //DTO (or Data Transfer Object) is an instance of a class
    var client = new HttpClient();
    await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, DTO);
}
```

and my method in my controller (my Web API project) is:

```
// POST: api/Clinics/createNewClinic
[ResponseType(typeof(Clinic))]
public IHttpActionResult createNewClinic(Clinic clinic)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.clinics.Add(clinic);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(clinic.clinicID);
}
```

These methods are working but I don't get `ClinicID` after inserting. What change do I have to do?

Is my code in my winform project correct ?

Comment: What is the value of `clinicID` on the last line of your code?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan clinicID is PK of clinic table that i want to return.

Comment: The **value**, man

Comment: @IvanStoev clinicID is PK of clinic table that i want to return

Comment: @HamletHakobyan was asking if the **value** is correct at that point, i.e. is **value** 1,2,3, etc. or stays 0. Come on, you know what **value** means.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan it returns a correct value but i cant get it in my windosform i think !

Comment: would it be `[ResponseType(typeof(int))]` ?  or `return Ok(clinic)`

Comment: Can you post the code where you're looking for the value in the return task?  Something like "var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri,DTO).Result"

I can't see where you're looking at the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are using your data models(of your EF generated classes) as a parameter. You should not expose your data models to your API that is because it can contain several other properties/members that are for internal/confidential use. Instead create view models (DTO) that are lightweight and pretty much contains only getters and setters.

In your code above, if you implement the view models(DTOs) in your API layer code, it can look like this:

```
var entity = db.Set<Clinic>().Create();

//mapping the values of your view models to data models
entity.Name = clinic.Name;
entity.Description = clinic.Descrption; 

//add 
db.clinics.Add(entity);
db.SaveChanges();

return Ok(entity.clinicID);
```